# How select hierarchy from child to parent using linq for entities or EF Core 2?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, parent-child

There is a hierarchy of four entities (models). All entities have relationships one to many. It's looks following:

```
public class Region
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
    }
    public class District
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int DistrictId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public Region Region { get; set; }
    }
    public class Building
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public int DistrictId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Flat> Flats { get; set; }
        public District District { get; set; }
    }
    public class Flat
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int FlatId { get; set; }
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public Building Building { get; set; }
    }
```

It is hierarchy like: Region->District->Building->Flat.

I want return collection of `Flat` thats include all related entities from top.
I do it folowing:

```
var flat = _context.Flats
                .Include(t => t.Building)
                .Include(b=>b.Building.District)
                .Include(b => b.Building.District.Region).GetPaged(PageNumber, 20);
```

But for some reason is return breaking result....

```
[{"id":"6cbb1431-36d4-490c-a047-c211e4db3bdd","flatId":29570,"roomsCount":1,"totalArea":41.95,"kitchenArea":11.85,"floor":21,"buildingId":130,"price":5725650.00,"building":{"id":"03baca1e-02e9-4ee0-ae47-920e3eb0d5bb","buildingId":130,"name":"NNN","queue":1,"housing":"1","districtId":13003,"flats":[
```

It breaks for some reason on `public virtual ICollection<Flat> Flats { get; set; }`. I can't remove it becasue it is needed for FK.

The following query works:

```
_context.Flat
   .Join(
      _context.Building,
      f => f.BuildingId,
      b => b.BuildingId,
      (f, b) =>
         new
         {
             f = f,
             b = b
         }
   )
   .Join(
      _context.District,
      temp0 => temp0.b.DistrictId,
      d => d.DistrictId,
      (temp0, d) =>
         new
         {
             temp0 = temp0,
             d = d
         }
   )
   .Join(
      _context.Region,
      temp1 => temp1.d.RegionId,
      r => r.RegionId,
      (temp1, r) =>
         new 
         {
             Id = temp1.temp0.f.Id,
             FlatId = temp1.temp0.f.FlatId,
             Floor = temp1.temp0.f.Floor,
             RoomsCount = temp1.temp0.f.RoomsCount,
             TotalArea = temp1.temp0.f.TotalArea,
             KitchenArea = temp1.temp0.f.KitchenArea,
             Price = temp1.temp0.f.Price,
             Building = new
             {
                 Id = temp1.temp0.b.Id,
                 BuildingId = temp1.temp0.b.Id,
                 Name = temp1.temp0.b.Name,
                 Queue = temp1.temp0.b.Queue,
                 Housing = temp1.temp0.b.Housing,
                 District = new
                 {
                     Id = temp1.d.Id,
                     DistrictId = temp1.d.DistrictId,
                     Name = temp1.d.Name,
                     Regions = new
                     {
                         Id = r.Id,
                         RegionId = r.Id,
                         Name = r.Name
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
   ).GetPaged(PageNumber, PageSize)
```

And it is return what i whant:

```
{
    "id": "a49a0a48-370b-46da-b6da-ea4040cc1431",
    "flatId": 84095,
    "roomsCount": 3,
    "totalArea": 76.5,
    "kitchenArea": 11.07,
    "floor": 18,
    "buildingId": 0,
    "price": 5567500,
    "building": {
        "id": "037c4074-3ff5-4fbd-92ea-88c8f746b883",
        "buildingId": 200,
        "name": "NNNN",
        "queue": 3,
        "housing": "4",
        "districtId": 0,
        "flats": null,
        "district": {
            "id": "db031e09-1d6c-41f4-9e45-ec6170e3df8b",
            "districtId": 5005,
            "name": "Distr",
            "buildings": null,
            "regionId": 0,
            "region": {
                "id": "5ac5766f-e62e-4da9-86cf-e4a85423503a",
                "regionId": 5001,
                "name": "Region",
                "districts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is looks like cumbersome.
How can I do it using EF features? Or maybe somehow to reduce linq? And why `include()` return breaking result?

P.S. `.GetPaged(PageNumber, 20);` is extension method for pagination and he is working fine.

Comment: Every Building has only one District and one Region, why don't you just add District = f.Building.District, Region = f.Building.District.Region?

Comment: I can't just add because by this models EF CodeFirst generate DataBase.

Comment: It's unclear what the actual problem is. `Include` query is perfectly fine, not sure what sure what you mean by "it is working slowly". Have you measured the EF query execution time? The generated SQL? At the end the problem if any might be in JSON serialization. Localize the problem before trying to solve it with redundant joins and projections.

Comment: I have corrected text. Please see above.

Comment: @Seva, for the Include way, I think you should create a dynamic class for the result Flat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggesstion is below

```
var flag = (from f in _context.Flags
       join b in _context.Buildings
       on b.BuildingId equals f.BuildingId
       join d in _context.Districts
       on d.DistrictId equals b.DistrictId 
       join r in _context.Regions
       on r.RegionId equals d.RegionId
       select new 
       { ... 
       }).GetPaged(PageNumber, 20);
```

You can get any property from Building, District and Region to populate to your result object.

Comment: Well, you've shown a standard LINQ join query. But in EF we don't use joins, but navigation properties. Because `b` is `f.Building`, `d` is `b.District` and `r` is `d.Region`. And joins are automatically provided by EF based on the model metadata. Hence this is equivalent of the original query with includes.

Comment: Maybe should give it a try, compare the SQL generated by 2 ways to check if any difference. I just want to say my way of query is probably the way with best performance.

Comment: It is works. Thank you. I have corrected text. Please see above.